# Using arc4random for multiple variables

Tags: ios, swift, arc4random

In my app, I have a title and artist that I want to appear randomly on the view controller, here's my relevent code:

```
        var songTitle = ["Happy", "Sad"]
        var aristTitle = ["The Happy Band", "The Sad Band"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            var random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(songTitle.count)))

            var titleOn = songTitle[random]

            titleText.text = titleOn
            artistText.text = ???
```

So, basically, if the title Happy randomly apears, I want the artist to be The Happy Band. But, if I use arc4random for the artist as well, there is a chance that the artist will be The Sad Band. How do I do this? (I'm using Swift 3 and Xcode 8)

Comment: why do you think  there is a chance that the artist can be "The Sad Band"?

Comment: You probably want to package the song and artists together in a struct or obejct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same index for both.

`artistText.text = artistTitle[random]`

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use the same random number to index into 2 different arrays. However, it would be better to create an array of structures, as @Alexander suggests in his comment

```
struct Song {
    var songTitle: String
    var aristTitle: String
}

var songs: [Song] = [
    Song(songTitle: "Happy", aristTitle:"The Happy Band"),
    Song(songTitle: "Sad", aristTitle:"The Sad Band")
];


let songIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(songs.count)))
let aSong = songs[songIndex]
let songTitle = aSong.songTitle
let artist = aSong.aristTitle
```